# IIS express worker crash MVC asp.net

Tags: express, iis, model-view-controller, crash

if I put in _layout.cshtml page this code

```
<div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="@Html.Action("Index", "Home")">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/Logo.jpg")" class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="Logo" />
            </a>       
        </div>
```

...IIS express worker process crash

why this beahvior ?
How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a mistake

@Url.Action rather than @Hmtl.Action

solved